# Transform movement bounds to local axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform

I have this code which works great, moving an object over local X-axis (that of the gameobject)

```
    var vel = rb2d.velocity;
    if (Input.GetKey(moveLeft)) {
        rb2d.velocity = -transform.right * speed;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(moveRight)) {
        rb2d.velocity = transform.right * speed;
    }
    else {
        rb2d.velocity = transform.right * 0;
    }
```

However I also need to limit it's movement over the local X-axis, but can't seem to figure this one out. So far I have this:

```
    var pos = transform.position;
    if (pos.x > boundX) {
        pos.x = boundX;
    }
    else if (pos.x < -boundX) {
        pos.x = -boundX;
    }
    transform.position = pos;
```

Which works great if the local X-axis is aligned with the world X-axis, but obviously I want it to work on the local X-axis for gameObjects that aren't. I can't seem to figure out how to transform the world points to local. I've been messing around with [InverseTransformPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformPoint.html), but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with some vector math.

First, find the object's offset in world space along its local x and y axis:

```
float xOffset = Vector2.Dot(transform.position,transform.right);
float yOffset = Vector2.Dot(transform.position,transform.up);
```

Then, clamp the `xOffset` to the bounds:

```
xOffset = Mathf.Clamp(-boundX,boundX,xOffset);
```

Then, apply the offsets back onto their axes and add them together to get the position:

```
transform.position = xOffset * transform.right + yOffset * transform.up;
```

Altogether:

```
float xOffset = Vector2.Dot(transform.position, transform.right);
float yOffset = Vector2.Dot(transform.position, transform.up);

xOffset = Mathf.Clamp(xOffset, -boundX, boundX);

transform.position = xOffset * transform.right + yOffset * transform.up;
```

Comment: This sort of works for 2 objects that are rotated 45 degrees, however the bounds are closer than they should be (object not covering entire distance). Objects that are rotated by a larger angle are either not moving at all or are bugging out.

Comment: Not exactly sure what I've done, but this works now, thanks a million!